# select row with multiple period time field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

i use asp.net mvc and c#
i have data table that have many column,one column has 'time' and sotred data like this format

```
14
16:30
17:05
...
```

in view i have filter for time and user can select multiple time from check box,
my filter check box is

```
4 - 8
8 - 11
11 - 14
14 - 17
17 - 21
21 - 24
```

now i want filter from datatable

```
var result = from r in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()  
             where r.Field<string>("time")  // between any passed time,like between 4-8 and 11-14 and 21-24
             select r;  
DataTable dtResult = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

my problem is,i dont know user how many pass time , if just passed one time it's easy but i dont know how many time passed

how i can edit code for accept any time and any count of time?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
string input = "4 - 17"; // The input from your check box

var sections = input.Split('-');
int beginHour = int.Parse(sections[0].Trim());
int endHour = int.Parse(sections[1].Trim());

var result = from r in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
             let time = int.Parse(r.Field<string>("time").Split(':')[0])
             where time >= beginHour && time < endHour
             select r;
```

*Make sure you handle cases where parsing to `int` might fail*

---

Of a collection of input ranges you can do something like:

```
List<string> originalData = new List<string> { "4 - 8", "8 - 11", "11 - 14", "14 - 17"};

var ranges = originalData.Select(item =>
{
    var sections = item.Split('-');
    return new
    {
        RangeBegin = int.Parse(sections[0].Trim()),
        RangeEnd = int.Parse(sections[1].Trim())
    };
}).ToList();

var result = from r in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
             let time = int.Parse(r.Field<string>("time").Split(':')[0])
             from range in ranges
             where time >= range.RangeBegin && time < range.RangeEnd
             select r;
```

Comment: ,thankyou for your help,but if i have multiple time,like this string input = "4 - 17, 21 - 24 , 8 - 11",in this case what i should do?

Comment: Thank's for your help

Comment: @JSon.Mvc - happy to hear it helped you :) (forgot to send you a notification when I added the collections part)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider storing your time in non-string format. Direct comparisons are difficult (i.e. "17" < "9" but 17 > 9). Remember, programs are algorithms + data structures.

```
var data = new[]
{
    new {Time = "6", Other = "Time6"},
    new {Time = "14", Other = "Time14"},
    new {Time = "16:30", Other = "Time1630"},
    new {Time = "17:05", Other = "Time1705"}
};

string[] inputs = {"4 - 8", "17 - 21"};

var result = from d in data
             let hour = Convert.ToInt32(d.Time.Split(':')[0])
             where inputs.Select(i =>
             {
                 var ranges = i.Split('-');
                 return new
                 {
                     From = Convert.ToInt32(ranges[0].Trim()),
                     To = Convert.ToInt32(ranges[1].Trim())
                 };
             }).Any(range => hour >= range.From && hour < range.To)
             select d;
```